# What am I doing to cause inconsistent output from this program?

Tags: c++, encryption, bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

So I made a basic xor encryption program that asks for a password string and uses it to seed [ISAAC](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html)

Then it asks for the string to be encrypted, and xor's it with the output from ISAAC.
For some reason, this is producing inconstant results for the same two string.
Is this a problem with my code, or that its being outputted to the console?
Am I doing something to make it glaringly obvious?
Here is my code, I am using the template class provided at ISAAC's site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::malloc;
using std::free;
#include "isaac.hpp"
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

QTIsaac<8,int> derp;



char trand(){
    int rando=0;
    rando=derp.rand();
    rando=abs(rando);
    rando=rando%256;
    char re=rando;
    return re;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "What is your password string?\n";
    string get;
    getline(cin,get);
    int length=get.size();
    int seedWithMe[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        seedWithMe[i]=(int)get[i];
    }
    derp.srand(1,1,1,seedWithMe);
    cout << "What is your string to be encrypted? \n";
    getline(cin,get);
    length=get.size();
    char table[length];
    char table3[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        table[i]=trand();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        table3[i]=(char)table[i]^(char)get[i];
    }

    cout << table3 << "\n";



    return 0;
}
```

Edit: nevermind, all of that was just me being stupid

> So I tried the fix David Schwartz gave me, but then when I tried to
>   hash the password, it quit working again. The function I am using to
>   hash the input string is:
>
> ```
> string shaOfPass(string digestThis){
>   string digest;
>   CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
> ```
>
> > ```
> >  CryptoPP::StringSource foo(digestThis, true,
> >    new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash,
> >       new CryptoPP::HexEncoder (
> >          new CryptoPP::StringSink(digest))));
> >   return digest;
> > } And this code results in inconstant output:
> > ```
>
> ```
> cout << "What is your password string?\n";
>   string get;
>   getline(cin,get);
>   string hashOfPass=shaOfPass(get);
>   int seedWithMe[256];
>   for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
>       seedWithMe[i]=(int)get[i%256];
>   }
> ```

Comment: This program is illegal C++. You cannot declare `char table[length]` where `length` is not a constant.

Comment: At first glance the problem is that the values of `table` will be different at each run, thus your output will be indeterminate.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: `gcc` allows it (but you are right, it is not part of the standard).

Comment: Where is the template class? I've searched the site and can't find the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The `srand` function, when given a pointer, requires that the pointer contains at least 2^N bytes of data (you've set N to 8). So you're seeding with some random, garbage data when your string is less than 256 characters long.

Here's a fix:

```
int length=get.size();
char seedWithMe[256];
for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
    seedWithMe[i]=get[i%length];
}
derp.srand(1,1,1,seedWithMe);
```

Comment: So if i hashed it with sha256 first, then it would be ok? (the crypto++ implementation that leaves a raw string with the output, not formatted in any base)
I assume you found the template class.

Comment: Not quite. SHA256 produces 256 *bits*. You need 256 *bytes*. If you want, you can SHA256 hash it 8 times, modifying it slightly between hashes. (For example, you could hash it, append a "." on the end it, hash it again, and so on.) If this is a real crypto application, I'd advise you to use an algorithm designed for this purpose such as RC4, which has a known-secure keying algorithm. (Or at least one whose weaknesses are well-studied.)

Comment: Ahh, misread there. I'm assuming that it would count each letter as one byte I could just concatenate the results of different types of hashes.

Comment: Also, thanks for the fix, its something I never would have gotten